# 02-08 10:11:26.825: E/WindowManager(17630): andrhas leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow that was originally added here

Tags: java, android, window, rss-reader

I have to develop one BBC_NEWS_READER android application from [here](https://github.com/okey666/BBC-News-Reader)

The app is force closed while run the application also gave me following error.
The error is :

```
       E/WindowManager(17630): Activity com.digitallizard.bbcnewsreader.ReaderActivity 
      has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4a4dc
       760 that was originally added here

        E/WindowManager(17630): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity 
        com.digitallizard.bbcnewsreader.ReaderActivity has leaked window
        com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4a4dc760 that was originally 
        added here
            at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:247)

        E/WindowManager(17630):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
         com.digitallizard.bbcnewsreader.Eula.show(Eula.java:87)

         E/WindowManager(17630):    at 
         com.digitallizard.bbcnewsreader.ReaderActivity.onCreate(ReaderActivity.java:444)
```

How can i resolve these error???
please help me.i have used same code as that github project.

Comment: move `Eula.show(this);` line after `this.setContentView(R.layout.reader_activity);` then try to run

Comment: Hi now also am getting same error :02-08 11:26:13.615: E/WindowManager(19151):  at com.digitallizard.bbcnewsreader.Eula.show(Eula.java:87)
02-08 11:26:13.615: E/WindowManager(19151):  at com.digitallizard.bbcnewsreader.ReaderActivity.onCreate(ReaderActivity.java:466)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `Eula.show(this);` line after setting the content view as below:

> ```
>  this.setContentView(R.layout.reader_activity);
>     Eula.show(this); // show the eula
> ```

Comment: Hi after i have moved the line i got the following error on my console window:http://pastie.org/private/d9l5f9lc97agtkjfzuseuq    please check it

Comment: Change the `onResume` code by `this.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(text);` and try out .

Comment: what is the meaing for these line: builder.create().show(); on Eula.java
  here ly i have faced problem

Comment: `obj.create()`-For create Dialog
`obj.show()`-For show Dialog <- without it you cant show dialog if you created.
and
`obj.create().show()`-create and show Dialog i mean both same as above two in one statement.

Comment: yes ...here i have to create the builder.create();builder.show(); means am getting the error on builer.show(); line.why am getting these error ???